# Find Loop Control Test Broken

Tags: loops, warnings

The Code:

```
Row = 1
LastRow = {some number}
Rng = "A" & Row ":" & "A" & LastRow
Do While Find_String(Rng,"Look for Something",Ans_Row) Then
   ...
   Row = Row + 1
   Rng = "A" & Row ":" & "A" & LastRow
Loop
```

If you get past the last row, Find_String" should return a False and loop should stop.

I have just found that if you get past the last and get a range like

```
"A5:A4"
```

the Find_String does NOT return from the loop anymore.  It used to.

The test you have to add to get it to work is

```
If Row > LastRow Then Exit Do
```

Comment: Which context is this running in?

Answer (score 0):

A CORRECTION

It should say that "Find_String" continues to return a TRUE even though the Range is, or at least until recently, use to return a FALSE.  It doesn't anymore.

Comment: Not an answer, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55596882/edit) button to modify the question